# Function to Remove Specific Strings from an Array - "console.log" and "return" Behaving Differently

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm working on an "edabit" challenge where I must create a function that removes specific strings from a function, and returns what's left into an array. Each call on the function provides a list of drinks as arguments. If "cola" or "fanta" are present they must be removed.

In the code, when I "console.log", the correct strings are output. However, for the challenge I must "return" the output. When I do, only the first non-cola/non-fanta string is returned. So in the examples below, I get "water" and "lemonade" only. Why are console.log and return behaving differently? Thank you.

```
// The "console.log" Version
function skipTooMuchSugarDrinks(drinks) {
    for (prop in drinks){
        if (drinks[prop] !== "cola" && drinks[prop] !== "fanta"){
            console.log (drinks[prop]);
        }
    }
}

// The "return" Version
function skipTooMuchSugarDrinks(drinks) {
    for (prop in drinks){
        if (drinks[prop] !== "cola" && drinks[prop] !== "fanta"){
            return drinks[prop];
        }
    }
}

// Function Calls
skipTooMuchSugarDrinks(["water", "tea"]);
skipTooMuchSugarDrinks(["lemonade", "beer", "fanta"])
```

Comment: return will ends the whole function.

Comment: do a console.log(skipTooMuchSugarDrinks(["lemonade", "beer", "fanta"]));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` version is returning as soon as it finds the first element that doesn't match one of the strings. That ends the function, and it never continues to look for other non-matching elements. A function can only return one thing.

You should put the elements you want to return in a new array, then return that at the end.

```
// The "return" Version
function skipTooMuchSugarDrinks(drinks) {
    var result = [];
    for (var prop in drinks){
        if (drinks[prop] !== "cola" && drinks[prop] !== "fanta"){
            result.push(drinks[prop]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

or simply use the built-in `filter()` method:

```
function skipTooMuchSugarDrinks(drinks) {
    return drinks.filter(drink => drink !== "cola" && drink !== "fanta");
}
```